# WCF Certificate-Based Authentication is accepting all the Cert Signed by the Same Root Certificate Authority

Tags: wcf, soap

My WCF Service is configured with Certificate-Based Authentication. The service has one issue; it is accepting all the certificates signed by the same Root Certificate Authority and not considering the thumbprint provided in the `serviceCertificate` tag. I am not sure is there any configuration part is missing in the config file. All my Certificates are stored an Personal root. Can anyone help me on this issue?

```
<basicHttpsBinding>
   <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding.ProcessUserInfo" transferMode="Streamed" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom" receiveTimeout="00:30:00">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="Transport">
         <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
   </binding>
</basicHttpsBinding>
<behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ProcessUserInfoServiceBehavior">
         <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="e3fd612e42d9d4c464c4d1c2f9a26a4068b81ee6" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
            <clientCertificate>
               <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
            </clientCertificate>
         </serviceCredentials>
         <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
         <CustomBehaviorExtensionElement/>
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
   <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MyAppBehavior">
         <KyPlanLoadSchemaValidator validateRequest="True" validateReply="False">
            <schemas>
               <add location="App_Data\service.xsd"/>
            </schemas>
         </KyPlanLoadSchemaValidator>
      </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
   <service name="MyApp.ProcessUserInfo" behaviorConfiguration="ProcessUserInfoServiceBehavior">
      <endpoint binding="basicHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBinding.ProcessUserInfo" contract="ProcessUserInfoService" behaviorConfiguration="MyAppBehavior" bindingNamespace="http://www.myapp.com/ex/service"/>
   </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score -2):

The code for creating an X509 certificate with makecert.exe is as follows:

```
public class T_CertInfo
{
public String FriendlyName;
public String Subject;
public DateTime BeginDate;
public DateTime EndDate;
public int SerialNumber;
}

/// summary
/// param name=makecrtPathmakecert  Process directory/param
/// param name=crtPath Temporary directory for certificate files/param
/// param name=certInfo Certificate information/param
/// returns/returns
public static X509Certificate2 CreateCertificate(String makecrtPath, String crtPath,
T_CertInfo certInfo)
{
Debug.Assert(certInfo != null);
Debug.Assert(certInfo.Subject != null);

string MakeCert = makecrtPath + makecert.exe;
string fileName = crtPath + cer;

string userName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

StringBuilder arguments = new StringBuilder();

arguments.AppendFormat(-r -n \{0}\ -ss my -sr currentuser -sky exchange ,
certInfo.Subject);

if (certInfo.SerialNumber 0)
{
arguments.AppendFormat(-# {0} , certInfo.SerialNumber);
}

arguments.AppendFormat(-b {0} , certInfo.BeginDate.ToString(@MM\/dd\/yyyy));
arguments.AppendFormat(-e {0} , certInfo.EndDate.ToString(@MM\/dd\/yyyy));
arguments.AppendFormat(\{0}\, fileName);
```